# How to locate a program?

Tags: 13.10

I installed PasswordSafe 0.93 beta by downloading its deb-package from SourceForge and have it taken care of using Ubuntu Software Center.

Now PasswordSafe asks me every time what psafe3-file to load instead of offering me a default one - as it used to be with the Windows version of it. So I thought about having a look at PasswordSafe and its (probably existing) config files and see if I can edit them appropriately. But this endeavour fails at locating the program and its related stuff.

How do I go about finding it?

Comment: actually it is - I tried which/whereis before but failed because I didn't know what is the cmd for PasswordSafe (pwsafe) - then stumbled up on it just now ...

Comment: try with the `locate` command in terminal, like so: `locate PasswordSafe`

Comment: @v2r: doesn't seem to work in this case

Comment: Ok then. I see Olupot Douglas answer worked out well (:

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you open terminal and type these

```
  which <program_name>
```

or

```
  whereis <program_name>
```

alternatively use this command

```
 dpkg -L 'packagename'
```

will display the path to the the files

Comment: `type -f <program` also works, `type <program>` without the -f will find a bash function.